# how to give simple test editing facility (bold,italic,underline) while typing text in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, rich-text-editor

the user should be able to create something like the following while typing inside the edittext itself.

"this text is **Bold** and this is *italics* ."

I don't want the whole text to be in any one format(ie. bold/italics/underline).

thank you.

Comment: Just curious on which base u determine text will be bold or italics or underline, as on native keypad there is no such options!?

Comment: i will add buttons to my activity to do the same

Comment: So u mean u have the button bold italic underline in activity and selected text in editext will change format as per button click.?

Comment: yes.. something like what we do in MS Word . for eg . while the "Bold" button is pressed , the text is displayed as bold and likewise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution which can help u .. first get the selected data of editext (on bold/italic/underline button click):

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
String text = et.getText();

int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

There is 2 way to set the style in edit text : [here option check is the button which got click ]

1)  use the html

```
if(option.bold) 
{
   text = text.replace(selectedText , "<b>"+ (selectedText + "</b>");
   et.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

 }
if(option.italic)  
{
    text = text.replace(selectedText , "<i>"+ (selectedText + "</i>");
    et.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));  
}
if(option.underline)  
{
    text = text.replace(selectedText , "<u>"+ (selectedText + "</u>");
    et.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));  
}
```

2) use the Spannable

```
 SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

 if(option.underline) 
           { 
     span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),startSelection, endSelection , 0); 
      }
   if(option.bold) 
    { 
       span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection ,  0);
      }
    if(option.italic) 
        {   
       span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection , 0);
      }
   et.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i resolved this problem...thanks everyone

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_bold:

        System.out.println("bold pressed");
        action_bold.setVisible(false);
        action_unbold.setVisible(true);
        content.append("<b>");

        return true;
    case R.id.action_unbold:

        System.out.println("unbolded pressed");
        action_bold.setVisible(true);
        action_unbold.setVisible(false);
        content.append("</b>");
        return true;

    case R.id.action_italics:

        System.out.println("italics pressed");
        action_italics.setVisible(false);
        action_unitalics.setVisible(true);
        content.append("<i>");

        return true;
    case R.id.action_unitalics:

        System.out.println("unitalics pressed");
        action_italics.setVisible(true);
        action_unitalics.setVisible(false);
        content.append("</i>");
        return true;
    case R.id.action_underline:

        System.out.println("underline pressed");
        action_underline.setVisible(false);
        action_ununderline.setVisible(true);
        content.append("<u>");

        return true;
    case R.id.action_ununderline:

        System.out.println("ununderline pressed");
        action_underline.setVisible(true);
        action_ununderline.setVisible(false);
        content.append("</u>");
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the text and do the Styles to the text and concatenate the split-ted String.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, you might as well want to try this?

[CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/FlatEarther/pen/rfwCu)

Credits to the author from CodePen.

Answer (score 0):

Try Html.fromHtml(), and mark up your text with bold and italic HTML tags

e.g.,

```
 Html.fromHtml("This mixes <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> stuff);
```

Comment: this works fine when i want to display it. but i dont expect the see the html tags while typing it.

Comment: i mean i dont expect my users to type/view the <u> ,<I> , <b> tags. i just want to see the effect. just like when we use text editors like MS Word.

Comment: i am using the code u said for displaying the text in a TextBox . but while allowing editing, these tags become visibe...hope i could explain the problem :)

Comment: finally solved the problem..appended the necessary code using buttons..thanks